# django : 404 (main.urls not included in myproject/urls.py?)

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have the following problem :

I've made a little django (1.7.8) project (named ***djangocmstest***) to test [django-cms](http://www.django-cms.org/en/) (but it could be related with just django, I'm not sure about this).

**I try to access *localhost:8000/one* and get the following issue :**

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/one/

Using the URLconf defined in djangocmstest.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^en/
    ^media\/(?P<path>.*)$

The current URL, one/, didn't match any of these.
```

I've made the following files :

**djangocmstest/urls.py :**

I added `url(r'^/', include('cms.urls')),` as suggested [here](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/support-3.0.x/how_to/install.html#url-configuration).

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                       # Please note that I'm not sure how to handle
                       # the order of the two following lines.
                       url(r'^/', include('main.urls')),
                       url(r'^/', include('cms.urls')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**main/urls.py :**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('main.views',
    url(r'^one/$', 'template_one'),
)
```

For some reason, the **main/urls.py** file content doesn't seem to be included into **djangocmstest/urls.py**.

How could I fix this?

**EDIT :**
With the correct URL (as suggested by @catavaran ) in the browser (".../en/one") I get the following :

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/one

Using the URLconf defined in djangocmstest.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^en/ ^admin/
    ^en/ ^/
    ^en/ ^/
    ^media\/(?P<path>.*)$

The current URL, en/one, didn't match any of these.
```

**EDIT 2 (FIXED) :**
I now have these files (and it works :) ) :

**main/urls.py :**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('main.views',
    url(r'^one/$', 'template_one'),
)
```

**djangocmstest/urls.py :**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                       url(r'^', include('main.urls')),
                       url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the project's `urls.py` you use the `i18n_patterns` instead of simple `patterns` so url for your page should be:

```
/en/one/
```

**UPDATE**: Remove the trailing slashes from the regexes in the project's `urls.py`.  So regex should be `r'^'` but not the `r'^/'`:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                       url(r'^', include('main.urls')),
                       url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: That could be that, I didn't think to this.
Do you mean just entering ".../en/one" in the browser? Or should I also replace *^one/$* in *main/urls.py** by *^/en/one$*?
In which order should I let the two includes in *djangocmstest/urls.py**? Is this order correct?

Comment: I mean entering `/en/one/` in the browser. The order of includes is correct and using the same regex for includes correct too. What happens when you add the trailing slash to the url? (`/en/one/` instead of `/en/one`)

Comment: Nothing new happens if I add a slash at the end of the url.

Comment: I got it, you use wrong regex in the project url patterns. See the update in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! main/urls.py is now included. :)
I can go through this error now.
I'll recapitulate the changes with an edit in my question.

Comment: I have a question : Why don't I have to remove the slash at the end of **r'^admin/'** too?

Comment: Look at the error page in the first edit of your question. Regexes are concatenated.  `"en/" + "admin/" == "en/admin/"` - a pretty valid url.  On the other hand `"en/" + "/" == "en//"`. This is why you should remove the slash from the "empty" regex - `"en/" + "" == "en/"`.

Comment: It makes sense. So I may add the slash to non-empty patterns. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expressions for `main.urls` and `cms.urls` should not include a forwards slash:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                       # Please note that I'm not sure how to handle
                       # the order of the two following lines.
                       url(r'^', include('main.urls')),
                       url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also, when you perform your query, make sure it is for

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/one/
```

since you do have a trailing slash in your `main.urls` file.

Comment: That was that. catavaran already suggested that but thank you too. :)

Comment: Glad to help. At the time I submitted my answer catavaran's answer was still showing the version his answer which dealt only with the `i18n_patterns` bit. Otherwise, I would not have submitted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two includes with the same regex. This way the include won't work. Try this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                       # Please note that I'm not sure how to handle
                       # the order of the two following lines.
                       url(r'^cms/', include('cms.urls')),
                       url(r'^/', include('main.urls')),

) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that is the opposite : **main** is the app and **djangocmstest** the project.

Comment: I wasn't sure about how to use these. So I should only use one of them? Which one? How to use the other? Should I include **main/urls.py** inside **cms.urls**?

Comment: My URL should look like *localhost:8000/en/one* (like catavaran said). the cms is here to read the first part of my URL (I'll make an edit to my question to add the new issue I got with the correct URL). So I'm not sure that **cms.urls** should be bound to the '^/cms' regex.

Comment: So my question to you is: what do you have installed? What is the "cms" app? Is it something you need to have a URL, or is it just an app? The way I'm looking now, The i18n will prepend the locale string, and then will include the "admin", "cms", "main" apps, and "/en/one" will match the "one" url pattern defined on main.urls.

Comment: I added two links in my question, one to django-cms website, and one to its documentation.

Comment: But you may be right, shouldn't the **/en** part be handled by **i18n_patterns()**?  I'll try to find more about this.

Comment: If you *don't* want to have "en" in your urls, use the simpler "patterns" instead of i18n_patterns.